# How can I animateTo diagonally in Compose and coroutineScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a box that I drag over and around (was a struggle, but I realised that the Kotlin SDK is actually really good with lots of examples).
now. I setup this box in a way that when it's clicks, and, or moved, it changes it size - it looks nice :).

Now, I wanted this box to get back to its original coordinate (for the time being it's 0,0 but, will change to some var in the future).

I am struggling with the diagonal movement. tried while loops, tried external functions, and a whole external class for calculating the smoother movement, but. even when I succeed to go forward a step, its performing so slow!! that I am starting to think that it's not the right way.

```
@Composable
fun drawText() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val enable = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        var offsetX  =  remember { Animatable(0f) }
        var offsetY  =  remember { Animatable(0f) }
        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        val clickable = Modifier.clickable(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = LocalIndication.current
        ) { }
        val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
        val size = animateSizeAsState(
            targetValue = if (enable.value && !isPressed) {
                Size(50f, 50f)
            } else {
                Size(100f, 100f)
            }
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), offsetY.value.roundToInt()) }
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .size(size.value.width.dp, size.value.height.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            enable.value = !enable.value
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consumeAllChanges()
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                offsetX.snapTo(offsetX.value + dragAmount.x)
                                offsetY.snapTo(offsetY.value + dragAmount.y)
                            }
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessHigh, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)

                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            enable.value = !enable.value
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                offsetY.animateTo(
                                    targetValue = 0f,
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 1000,
                                        delayMillis = 0
                                    )
                                )
                                offsetX.animateTo(
                                    targetValue = 0f,
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 1000,
                                        delayMillis = 0
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                .then(clickable)
        )
    }
}
```

This code moves it first to 0 y and than to 0 x .. which is not the outcome I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animateTo` is a `suspend` function, which means your X animation only will start when Y animation finishes.

You can launch an other coroutine to run them in parallel:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    launch {
        offsetY.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 1000,
                delayMillis = 0
            )
        )
    }
    offsetX.animateTo(
        targetValue = 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
            delayMillis = 0
        )
    )
}
```

An other option is animating the offset, instead of animating each parameter. Here's how you can use animatable with `Offset`:

```
val offset = remember { Animatable(Offset.Zero, Offset.VectorConverter) }

// onDrag: 
offset.snapTo(offset.value + dragAmount)

// onDragEnd:
offsetY.animateTo(
    targetValue = Offset.Zero,
    // ...
```

Comment: Pylyp, thanks allot for the help!! works like charm.
Also, are there any benefits for using the 2nd method?

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. If this solved your question, please upvote it and accept using a checkmark under the votes counter. Voting and accepting are the most appropriate ways to thank someone on SO, see [Why is voting important?]. I find the second approach cleaner - X and Y are not unrelated objects, they both describe the position of the same element, so it is better to group them, especially when you do not need to create your own container but can reuse system one.